# Firefox Quantum Shortcut on taskbar

Tags: windows-10, firefox-quantum

With older version of Firefox Quantum, you could right click the icon on the window taskbar and open either regular window or private broswer depending on your needs.

For some reason or another, that shortcut is gone. All I have is "X Close all Window" whenever I right click firefox quantum on taskbar.

I don't like that I have to "open" a regular firefox quantum window first to be able to ctrl+shift+p or whatever to go directly to privacy mode.

Chrome's right click seem to work as per usually.

Comment: Check if my answer here solves your problem: https://superuser.com/a/1295980/358758

Comment: Actually the issue somehow resolved by itself a long time ago I all but forget about this question.