# Firefox taskbar options are gone in Windows 10, how to fix?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, taskbar, context-menu

I have the Mozilla Firefox pinned to taskbar in Windows 10. Right-clicking the taskbar icon should bring some options like:

- Open new tab
- Open new window
- New private window

Suddenly, one day, I noticed these options were gone:

[image: firefox taskbar right-click menu without said options]

What might have caused this, and how to fix it?

I tried reinstalling Firefox, refreshing it, and even deleting the profile folder altogether from `%appdata%`, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What might have caused this?

Just another random bug, it seems. It might have been caused by restarting Windows while it was downloading updates, which is a lame excuse indeed but it’s the only thing I can think of.

> How to fix it?

**I found that this works:**

1. Access `about:config` from the address bar.
2. Look for a setting called `browser.taskbar.lists.enabled`.
3. Double-click it to set its value to **false**
4. Double-click it again to (re)set its value to **true**, which is the default.

And now it’s fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If it behaves like this and you unpin it and try to manually pin Firefox.exe, it may show this behavior (no private browsing) and a duplicate Firefox icon when you run it.

The fix: Right-click the new icon which appears when you run Firefox on taskbar, and pin it to Taskbar. Remove the first one.

(this may serve someone looking up the very similar issue, because your problem is the closest to this bug)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).